# EF One to Many Displays Only First Record

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've got an issue where a one to many (a volunteer should have many AspNetUserRole) only displays one role ever in the results.

```
        var test2 = from a in _context.Volunteer.Where(a => a.AspNetUserId == "25a6aef9-cc59-4bbc-bd9d-078d2asaa560") select a.AspNetUserRoles;
        var sql = test2.ToQueryString();
```

The "sql" value is perfect - if run against the database manually, it return 3 results. However, using the debugger to navigate to test2's roles returns only one value. Does anyone have any insight why this would be?

```
public class Volunteer : BaseVolunteer
{
}

public abstract class BaseVolunteer
{
    [Key]
    public String AspNetUserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //[Required] //This was removed because FamilyMembers inherit this and it is not required for that
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    public virtual City City { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    //[ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserRole> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; } 
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Family")]
    public List<FamilyMember> FamilyMembers { get; set; }
}

public class AspNetUserRole
{
    [Key]
    public String UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    //[ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think the application is not running in the same database as when you run the script manually :)  Check your connection string again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var test2 = _context.Volunteer
.Where(a => a.AspNetUserId == "25a6aef9-cc59-4bbc-bd9d-078d2asaa560") 
.Select(a=> a.AspNetUserRoles).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You missed the OP's point  `The "sql" value is perfect - if run against the database manually, it return 3 results. However, using the debugger to navigate to test2's roles returns only one value.`. He doesn't know why getting one recore while when executing the raw SQL in SSMS he get 3 recrords.

Answer (score -1):

The issue turned out to be incorrectly specified key on my part. The key on the UserRole table is actually a composite key. Adding the following code in OnModelCreating resulted in 3 records coming back.

modelBuilder.Entity().HasKey(c => new { c.UserId, c.RoleId });

Ultimately somewhat odd behavior to me - I get that something 'wrong' should occur for incorrectly specified keys, but I wouldn't have expected dropped records. Still not really sure what the root cause of the Entity Framework behavior is.